# How to search a substring of a LPWSTR?

Tags: c++, windows

Is there any function that is used for searching a substring of `LPWSTR`?

```
LPWSTR a_string = _T("abcdef");
    
if (a_string .find(L"def") != std::string::npos)
{
    
}
```

Comment: [wcsstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strstr-wcsstr-mbsstr-mbsstr-l?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @drescherjm not quite - that's just a macro to a `wchar_t*`. There's no need to use Win32 functions but using such arrays is frowned upon in general. It's better to use `wstring` or in recent C++ versions `u16string`

Comment: @Razec you don't need that LPWSTR to begin with. You can work with either `wstring` or `u16string` and use [either wide or Unicode literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-160). You can actually write `auto a_string = L"abcdef";` or `auto a_string=u"abcdef";`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: *you don't need that LPWSTR to begin with*. More or less... Both the WinAPI functions and the Microsoft Foundation Classes make a heavy use of it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta it's a macro, not a type. During compilation that's nothing more than a `wchar_t*`. The APIs accept a `wchar_t*`.  You don't need to use that macro at all. In fact, unless you intend to compile for ASCII, none of those macros is needed. They're a remnant of 1990s naming conventions. By 2000 this Hungarian notation was already considered a very bad idea, regularly blasted at "C/C++ Users Journal"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do know that. But using the API or MFC without its documentation is not easy, and that doc is cluttered with those old style macros. I know that it is possible to remove them and directly use C++ type or standard library types and macros but I prefere using copy/paste from the doc, or let MSVC wizard provide interfaces, both ways putting `LPWSTR` in my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That initialization of `a_string` is invalid, `LPWSTR` can't be initialized pointing to a string literal, you need `LPCWSTR`.

This being a glorified pointer to `wchar_t`, or more accurately a macro that will end up expanding to `wchar_t*`, it does not have member methods, it is not a class like `std::string`. You will need to do it another way, like the one [pointed out by Dialecticus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strstr-wcsstr-mbsstr-mbsstr-l?view=msvc-160), example:

```
LPCWSTR a_string = L"abcdef"; 
// or better yet
// auto a_string = L"abcdef"; 

if (wcsstr(a_string, L"def"))
{
    //...
}
```

You can avoid this altogether, if possible, by using [`std::wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) like pointed out by Panagiotis Kanavos in the comment bellow.

Comment: `a glorified pointer` not even that, it's just a macro. There's no need to use it either, the equivalent would be a `wstring` or `u16string`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes and yes. I suspect this is for academic purposes.

Comment: `if UNICODE is defined` it should always be. Windows (the NT line) is a Unicode OS with the ASCII functions essentially acting as wrappers. The macros are a remnant of the Windows 95 line and the transition period in the early 2000s. It's enough to write `auto a_string = L"abcdef";`. The [Microsoft C++ docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=msvc-160) don't use these macros

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, for sure, but MS seems to forget that at times, my VS came with multibyte as default encoding for new projects.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Like Serge mentioned, if you are in deep in the Windows API, you still have to use things like LPSTR and friends sometimes.